# How to get the Camera direction vector?

Tags: python, maya

I need to know the direction that a giving camera is looking at but i can't find a way to get it.Is there a way to get some kind of vector that tells which direction the camera is pointing to(just like there is an up vector telling the camera's up direction)?

Answer (score 2):

You can also get the camera's worldMatrix using xform.  The 3rd row of
the camera matrix is the *reverse* of the camera vector

```
camera_z = cmds.xform("persp", q=True,m=True, ws=True)[8:11]
forward = [i * -1 for i in camera_z]
```

Answer (score 0):

camera is looking on

```
centerOfInterest = cmds.camera(cameraShape, q=True, centerOfInterest=True)
```

camera world up vector

```
worldUp = cmds.camera(cameraShape, q=True, worldUp=True)
```

check the [camera docu](http://download.autodesk.com/us/maya/2011help/CommandsPython/camera.html)